# Shell command fails from python, ok from shell

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a python script that generates a number of shell commands from the given input. The problem is that when it tries to execute the generated commands, it fails, but when i run the generated commands myself (that is, from the command line), they are executed successfully.

Here is the generated command:
`find /home/me/downloader/0-29/ -type f | grep -i .rpm$ | xargs -i cp {} /home/me/downloader/builds/0-29/`

Here is the error message when it is run by the python script:

```
find: paths must precede expression: |
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Could you help me understand what the problem is?

**UPD**: Here is the function i use for executing the generated commands: 
`def exec_command(command):
        process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        output = process.communicate()[0]
        return output`

Comment: how are you executing that line from python? provide some code?

Comment: You might need to quote your command in python to execute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your command is a pipeline, you must set `shell=True` so that subprocess will send the command, as is, to the shell:

```
command = 'find /home/me/downloader/0-29/ -type f | grep -i .rpm$ | xargs -i cp {} /home/me/downloader/builds/0-29/'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Or,

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()[0]
return output
```

Also, do not do splitting in python on a command with a pipeline.  This will result in `find` being passed `|` as one of its arguments instead of as a shell operator.

It also appears that the command can be simplified:

```
command="find /home/me/downloader/0-29/ -type f -iname '*.rpm' -exec cp {} /home/me/downloader/builds/0-29/ \;"
```

Since the above is no longer a pipeline, it could, with a minor modification, be split and given to subprocess with shell=False.  The modification is that the single-quotes around `'*.rpm'` are there to protect the glob from shell expansion.  With shell=False, the shell doesn't remove them.  So, we have to.  For shell=False and for use with `command.split()`:

```
command="find /home/me/downloader/0-29/ -type f -iname *.rpm -exec cp {} /home/me/downloader/builds/0-29/ \;"
```

Comment: I think you messed up your quotes in the simplified version.

Comment: The single quotes around `*.rpm` are only necessary when the command line is processed by the shell, to prevent pattern expansion; the shell then removes the quotes before passing the literal string to `find`. With `shell=False`, you want to leave the single quotes out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe *what you do* is you start a single program called `find` with many parameters, incl. `|` and `grep` and `xargs` - and these are not arguments to find.

What you *want to do* is probably to ask bash to run `find` and then pipe the outcome to `grep`, etc. One way to do that is to execute a single command called `bash` with two parameters (`-c`) and a whole string incl. piped commands, e.g.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["bash", "-c", "cat /etc/issue | grep a"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output=process.communicate()[0]
print output
```